# Calculation of residuals with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to create a residual for this graph:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[,width=\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            grid=major,
            xmin=-50, xmax=670,
            ymin=18.4, ymax=25.2,
            xlabel=$t(s)$,
            ylabel=$T(^{\circ} \mathrm{C})$,
            tick style={thick},
            ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
            xtick={-50,0,...,650},
            ytick={19,20,...,25}, minor ytick={19.5,20.5,...,24.5}
        ]
        \addplot[black,thin,samples=100,domain=-50:625] {0.007303*x+19.8545};
        \addplot [blue, thin, only marks,mark=*] coordinates { 
            (0,20) (60,20.1) (120,20.6) (180,21.2) (240,21.7) (300,22.2) (360,22.5) (420,23.0) (480,23.1) (540,23.8) (600,24.3)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{figure}

It looks like this:
[image]

And the residual that i want to create has to look something like this:
[image]
I can't seem to find anything about this particular style of residual, and since i'm totally new to LaTeX i have no idea how i would create something like this.

Since i'm already making this post, i have a few problems with the graph in general that i would like help with too.

1. The `xlabel` and `ylabel` is at the end of each axis. If i wanted to move them underneath and besides the axis instead, how would i do that? Like it is shown in this example:
   [image]
2. I would like for the left outer line of the grid to be removed, while still keeping the tick at `-50` around.
3. If i wanted to make some floating text besides the linear function, with the text `0.007303x+19.8545`, how would i do that? Alternatively i could add a `legend` in the top left corner.
4. Why doesn't the `0` tick show on the x-axis. I can't seem to make it appear.

Comment: The x- and ylabel are there in your screenshot, at the ends of the axis lines.

Comment: Oh, of course. I'm a dummy, my bad!

Comment: I've rephrashed the question now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the residual, one obvious approach is to calculate the values in some other program, and make a new list of coordinates, just like you did for the original data.

You can also do it with `pgfplots`, if you read the data into a `pgfplotstable` table. If the table is called `\MyData`, you can do e.g.

```
\addplot [mark=*,blue, only marks]
    table[
      x=x,
      y expr={\thisrow{y}-f(\thisrow{x})}
    ] {\MyData};
```

where `f(x)` is a function I defined with

```
\tikzset{
  declare function={
    f(\x) = {0.007303*\x+19.8545}; % for convenience
  }
}
```

For the other questions:

1. Might be better options, but this works:

   ```
       xlabel style={at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},below},
       ylabel style={at={(yticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,above},
   ```
2. You could use an `extra x tick` for this, e.g.

   ```
       xtick={0,50,...,650}, % <-- start at zero
       extra x ticks={-50}, % <-- added
       extra x tick style={grid=none}, % <-- added
   ```
3. You can simply append a `node` at the end of the `\addplot`, e.g.

   ```
   \addplot[black,thin,samples=100,domain=-50:625] {f(x)} node[above left] {$0.007303x+19.8545$};
   ```
4. Tick labels at axis intersections are hidden by default, add

   ```
   hide obscured x ticks=false
   ```

Complete code below. I didn't add any styling of the residual plot. Should it be immediately below the main plot?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % <-- pgfplotstable instead of pgfplots (the former loads the latter)
\pgfplotstableread{
x y
0   20
60   20.1
120   20.6
180   21.2
240   21.7
300   22.2
360   22.5
420   23.0
480   23.1
540   23.8
600   24.3
}\MyData

\tikzset{
  declare function={
    f(\x) = {0.007303*\x+19.8545}; % for convenience
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$t(s)$},
            ylabel={$T\left(^{\circ} \mathrm{C}\right)$},
            width=\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            grid=major,
            xmin=-50, xmax=670,
            ymin=18.4, ymax=25.2,
            xlabel style={at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},below},
            ylabel style={at={(yticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,above},
            tick style={thick},
            ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize},
            xtick={0,50,...,650}, % <-- start at zero
            extra x ticks={-50}, % <-- added
            extra x tick style={grid=none}, % <-- added
            ytick={19,20,...,25},
            minor ytick={19.5,20.5,...,24.5},
            hide obscured x ticks=false % <-- added
        ]
        \addplot[black,thin,samples=100,domain=-50:625] {f(x)} node[above left] {$0.007303x+19.8545$};
        \addplot [blue, thin, only marks,mark=*] table {\MyData};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [mark=*,blue, only marks]
    table[
      x=x,
      y expr={\thisrow{y}-f(\thisrow{x})}
    ] {\MyData};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! If i wanted to add the node in question 3 besides the function instead, how would i do that? Example: https://gyazo.com/fc5443226c87af5291009a14b9d55a45

Comment: @Nikolai Sorry for the late reply. `node[pos=0.5,below right] {$0.007303x+19.8545$}`